# Speaker diarization model in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, diarization

I’m looking for a model (in Python) to speaker diarization (or both speaker diarization and speech recognition). I tried with pyannote and resemblyzer libraries but they dont work with my data (dont recognize different speakers). Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio.

A tutorial on how to perfrom speaker diarization with pyannote-audio can be found here:

https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/blob/master/notebooks/introduction_to_pyannote_audio_speaker_diarization_toolkit.ipynb